# How to highlight active page on website with html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to code (started last month) and I've been trying to highlight the link to the active page on my website. I've used several different methods and can't find out whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<nav>
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active-page">Home</a>
    <li><a href="page1.html"> History</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html"> Ownership</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html"> Purchase</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the HTML for the nav bar first page of my website

```
Header{
    Background-color:#0D2831;
    Color:  #35d6c6;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    Min-Height:90px;
    border-bottom :#5292A7;
    font-family:font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    Text-transform:Uppercase;
    min-height:180px;
}

Header a{
    text-decoration:None;
    Text-transform:None;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#35d6c6;
}

Header ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

Header li{
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

Header #logo{
    float:left;
}

Header #logo h1{
    margin:0;
}

header nav{
    float: right;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}

Header .hilight, a{
    color:  #FFFFFF;
}

Header a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

header nav .activepage{
    Background-color:white;
}
```

This is the CSS for the entire header which contains the navigation.

If anybody would be able to tell me what I am either missing or doing wrong that is preventing the active page from highlighting any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for active page add some css in your stylesheet like

```
.active-page{
   background-color:red;
   border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see one wrong text so you can try change it as below:
Before :

```
header nav .activepage{
    Background-color:white;
}
```

After:

```
header nav .active-page{
    Background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css to reflect the correct classname.

```
header nav .active-page {
    background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply

```
nav .active-page {
Background-color:white;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
        $("ul li a").removeClass(".active-page");
        $(this).addClass(".active-page");
    });
});
```

*You can now add js also*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).